# Joining computed column with its uncomputed version to show another column with a name

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I'm not sure exactly how to say it, let me try with a simple example. I have 3 tables with following columns:

```
table1
ID_TRANSACTION
ID_PRODUCT
SALES_DATA

table2
ID_PRODUCT
PRODUCT_DATA
ID_CATEGORY

table3
ID_CATEGORY
NAME_CATEGORY
CODE_CATEGORY
LEVEL
```

Categories in table2 have different levels, each level adds three extra digits. So level one 1 starts with '001', than level 2 has six '001001' level 3 '001001001' etc. What I need is a query the will give me SALES_DATA, PRODUCT DATA and NAME_CATEGORY from level 2, even if the product is on higher level. Say a product has CODE_CATEGORY 002005021, I need the NAME_CATEGORY of 002005, not NAME_CATEGORY of full 002005021. I know how to extract those digits:

```
SUBSTRING(tree.KOD_TREE,1,6)
```

but how do I make it show the NAME_CATEGORY connected with the 6-digit CODE_CATEGORY not its 9-digit one?

The code without that would look something like:

```
SELECT
table1.SALES_DATA
table2.PRODUCT_DATA
table3.NAME_CATEGORY
LVL2_NAME_CATEGORY /* (here I would put the NAME_CATEGORY from lower level) */

FROM
db.table1
INNER JOIN db.table2 ON table1.ID_PRODUCT = table2.ID_PRODUCT
INNER JOIN db.table3 ON table2.ID_CATEGORY = table3.ID_CATEGORY
```

Comment: Please tag the RDMS (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostGreSQL, SQLite, DB2, Teradata, MS Access, ...) you use as each carry different SQL dialects and different string functions.

Comment: Looks bad design? why not add another column with level info and use that to filter the data?

Comment: Added the tags.
There is another column if I need filtering, but that's not what I was looking for. Say you have lvl1 'vehicle', then lvl2 like 'car', 'bike', 'magic carpet' and then on lower levels you keep dividing them into smaller categories going something like vehicles>car>mazda>2016. If I queried the NAME_CATEGORY I would get '2016', but what I wanted was 'car'. Self join proposed by Parfait solves that. I guess I worded it poorly in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a `LEFT JOIN` on a table3  [self join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) using the `SUBSTRING()` value:

```
SELECT 
       table1.SALES_DATA,
       table2.PRODUCT_DATA,
       table3.NAME_CATEGORY,
       levelsub.NAME_CATEGORY AS LOWER_LEVEL_CATEGORY

FROM db.table1 
INNER JOIN db.table2 ON table1.ID_PRODUCT = table2.ID_PRODUCT 
INNER JOIN db.table3 ON table2.ID_CATEGORY = table3.ID_CATEGORY
LEFT JOIN db.table3 AS levelsub 
       ON levelsub.CODE_CATEGORY = SUBSTRING(table3.CODE_CATEGORY,1,6)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was searching for, but couldn't find for the lack of SQL-speak. I went around it by creating a new view and referencing it, but with self join I don't create any unnecessary views.

Comment: No, no we wouldn't want that. Glad I could help.